# Is there any function faster than Directory.Delete(path, true) to recursively delete all folder, subfolder and content?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have been using Directory.Delete(String, Boolean) from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxeahc5f(v=vs.110).aspx) to remove main folder, its subfolders and its content.

Is there any faster way of deleting the main folder than the method above?

Thank you

Comment: [Ask Me](https://www.google.com/search?q=function+faster+than+directory.delete&spell=1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjzks-wgObXAhWJuI8KHX69CbAQvwUIIygA&biw=1366&bih=637)

Comment: Probably not, but you could compare by running the command: rmdir /s /q folder